# Getting text value without any nested element within span tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to do this in jQuery:

```
$('span').contents()[0].nodeValue = "new text ";
```

How do I do it in plain JavaScript?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].firstChild.nodeValue="New text";
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="New text";
```

Using the Selectors API:

```
document.querySelector("span").firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5vsr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("span").firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";
```

or (This Methode `Delete All Values` Inside The Child)

```
 document.querySelector("span").childNodes[0].innerHTML = "NewText";
```

Or (If You want to `Append` Text)

```
document.querySelector("span").childNodes[0].innerHTML += "NewText";
```

Or As My Friend Said:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].firstChild.nodeValue="New text";
```

Or

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="New text";
```

Be Aware `InnerHTML` Is Considered A Very Bad Practice And i prefer to use `node value`